# Rails 4 Devise Non-Lazy Function Overloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, devise, controllers

I have two devise models- Worker and User. The worker signup requires additional attributes not specific to user.

I was running my user signup through the application controller

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :email, :firstName, :lastName, :dateofBirth, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip)}
end
```

However, when I added my worker sign up, I decided to go the nonlazy way, created my Worker controller via

```
    rails generate devise:controllers Worker
```

And proceeded to the registration controller in worker. There I un-hashed the before-filter and added a params filter after searching Google and StackOflow to figure out how to do this. Also went into the Github devise source code and copied and pasted their create code in their registration controller. My controller looks like this:

```
class Workers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
def create
build_resource(registration_params)

resource.save
yield resource if block_given?
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
end
#super
end
protected
 def registration_params
 params.require(:worker).permit(:username, :password, :email, :firstname, :lastname, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip)
end
# If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:username, :password, :email, :firstname, :lastname, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip)}
end
end
end
```

The data still shows up as nil on my console. Why is the data not saving and how do I get the data to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK for anyone who finds and can understand this- the answer is STI.

http://adamrobbie.me/blog/2013-3-29-sti-with-rails-40-beta-and-devise